# Data Type of any Variable as Variable Name in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, sqldatatypes, alias-data-type

Why do we mention data type of any variable as variable name itself in SQL Server?

Please help me understand these.

Ex:

```
@OurBranchID BranchID,  
@ApplicationID ApplicationID,  
@Ispassed Bit = 0 OUTPUT,  
@Remarks Remarks = NULL OUTPUT
```

This might be a noob query but I have always used regular data types for declaring variables. Was checking a stored procedure where I encountered such datatype. Also, checked the structure of other tables which had kinda similar datatypes

Comment: I'm not sure why people use them, it's an extra layer of abstraction for questionable gain and downright inconvenience. I've been [recommending against them for years](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-alias-types).

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I'm amazed MS still hasn't given use `ALTER TYPE` - as long as that doesn't exist, user-defined types are IMHO utterly useless.....